# Preventing duplicate files in an input file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, upload, lodash

I'm using loodash cloneDeep to upload files, however I need files to not be duplicated and only be able to upload a file once. How can I do this using cloneDeep?

I don't know how to do it, I googled, but the solution was only for jquery

```
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

    const onSelectFile = (e) => {
        try {
         let fileArr = cloneDeep(files);
            let promises = [];
            for (let file of e.target.files) {
                promises.push(
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const fileName = file.name
                        const type = file.type;
                        let reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        reader.onload = function (evt) {
                            const fileData = evt.target.result;
        
                            fileArr.push({
                                name: fileName,
                                type: type,
                                data: fileData,
                                comment: "",
                                id: `${new Date().getTime()}_${fileName}`,
                                canDelete: true
                            });
        
                            if (typeof props.onFileSelected == "function")
                                props.onFileSelected(fileArr);

                            resolve(true);
                        }
                        reader.onerror = function (evt) {
                            console.log("error reading file");
                            reject(false);
                        }
                    })
                );
            }

            Promise.all(promises).then(r => {
                setFiles(fileArr);
            })
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you rely only on the fileName ?

Comment: I think yes, I need that when uploading a file, only 1 name is displayed and that it is not possible to upload files with the same name

Comment: Okay let me try to write a response

Answer (score 0):

If relying on the filenames is enough, you can try to store them to check if it has been uploaded already :

```js
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

//state to store uploaded file's name
const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState([]);

const onSelectFile = (e) => {
    try {
        let fileArr = cloneDeep(files);
        let promises = [];
        for (let file of e.target.files) {
            promises.push(
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const fileName = file.name
                    //if the file has not been already uploaded
                    if (!fileNames.includes(fileName)) {
                        //add the current fileName in state
                        setFileNames([fileName, ...fileNames]);
                        const type = file.type;
                        let reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        reader.onload = function (evt) {
                            const fileData = evt.target.result;
    
                            fileArr.push({
                                name: fileName,
                                type: type,
                                data: fileData,
                                comment: "",
                                id: `${new Date().getTime()}_${fileName}`,
                                canDelete: true
                            });
    
                            if (typeof props.onFileSelected == "function")
                                props.onFileSelected(fileArr);
    
                            resolve(true);
                        }
                        reader.onerror = function (evt) {
                            console.log("error reading file");
                            reject(false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("File has already been uploaded");
                        reject(false);
                    }
                })
            );
        }

        Promise.all(promises).then(r => {
            setFiles(fileArr);
        })
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Note: this will not prevent the case when the user upload a file, then refresh the website and upload the same file again
If you want to prevent that you have to ask your backend if the file has already been upload or not.